# <ul> with overflow-y: auto and <li>s with relative position behaves oddly

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I've the following mark up

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span4">
        <ul class="test">
            <li>Arun</li>
            <li>Krishna</li>
            <li>Soundar</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And css

```
.test {
    height: 500px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding: 10px 4px 70px;
}
```

And script

```
$('.test li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
})
```

If you drag the items to the right side, it disappears, I don't know why it is behaving so.

If the `overflow-y: auto;` style is removed from `.test` it works fine.

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/br57F/1/)
You may have to increase the width of the preview tab because of the responsive css to replicate the issue in the fiddle

Comment: you mean: drag it to the left side it disappeas??

Comment: @caramba yes drag the items to the right

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I think I found an answer. The reason the list disappears is because you drag it off the edge of the div and it begins to auto scroll. So, you you just remove it from the flow of the page when it is clicked on, like so:

```
$('.test li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
}).mousedown(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    //create div to fill the vacated space
    $div = $('<div></div>');
    $div.width(that.width());
    $div.height(that.height());
    $div.insertAfter(that);
    //remove from flow of the page, set a different background color to see it work
    that.css({'position':'absolute'});
});
```

New fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/br57F/9/)

Comment: Your code has a bug. You should remove the created new `div` on mouse-up else each time we drag an item it create a new `div`!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the CSS on `bootstrap-combined.min.css`. It sets some width due to that it causes the issue.

So remove `bootstrap-combined.min.css` and try.

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/br57F/4/)**

### UPDATE:

Add `border: 1px solid;` to your `.test` class then you will see the actual difference, why it is working if you comment `overflow`

If you debug on firebug, you will see below CSS class (that is from *`bootstrap-combined.min.css`*) is causing your issue

```
.row-fluid .span4 {
    width: 31.4917%;
}
```

Comment: @ArunPJohny:Add border: 1px solid; to your .test class then you will see the actual difference, why it is working if you comment overflow

Answer (score 0):

All you required was, the 'min-width:1100px', and 'width:100%;'

I have updated fiddle for you

```
 Fiddle Link : http://jsfiddle.net/br57F/5/
```

Its working fine. overflow works with content, while draggable, will not add content to parent div. it will just change position in run time of the element.

I hope this will do :)

Comment: I cannot change the width of the `ul` since it is a grid system

Comment: then you may not add `overflow-y: auto` instead add `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0):

Just during drag, wrap dragged element by a `div` include `position:absolute` style.

**So instead this code:**

```
$('.test li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid'
})
```

**Use this one:**

```
$('.test li').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    start: function(event, el){
          $(el.helper[0]).wrap( "<div style='position:absolute;'></div>" );
     },
    stop: function(event, el){
          $(el.helper[0]).unwrap();
     }
});
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/br57F/38/)**